# How to modify ImageButton layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TableRow where I add some items to be shown and everything goes alright. Nevertheless, when I want to add a layout-modified button it just does not appear to be painted. Here is the code:

```
ImageButton botonBorrar = new ImageButton(this);

botonBorrar.setImageResource(R.drawable.discard_light);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

buttonParams.setMargins(15, 10, 10, 10);
botonBorrar.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

myRow.addView(botonBorrar);
```

What could be wrong here?. I have followed a lot of posts about this but nothing seems to correct my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should use TableRow.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

So you can add button to the view first and then get already generated layoutparams and modify them:

```
myRow.addView(botonBorrar);  
TableRow.LayoutParams buttonParams = (TableRow.LayoutParams)bottonBorrar.getLayoutParams();
buttonParams.setMargins(15, 10, 10, 10);
//botonBorrar.setLayoutParams(buttonParams); - if you add button to the view, you do not have to set modified layout params explicitly.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked !!. Nevertheless, it does not seem to keep the height parameters I set to the row. I can do it by setting the height of one of the TextView's I use to populate the row, but cannot manage to get it by setting   TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    100); It will just ignore the 100 pixels height

Comment: well, I think the problem lies in NEW  layoutparams. If you add view to the layout, layoutparams of that view are generated automatically - and absolutely correctly for the system. So modifying these automaticaly generated layoutparams you can change the layout. I tested next line: 
  TableRow.LayoutParams buttonParams2 = (TableRow.LayoutParams) botonBorrar2
    .getLayoutParams();
  buttonParams2.height = 800;
and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot Magarita. I think I am understanding it now. It is just a matter of getting the already existing layout and not overwriting it.